# Filtering SQL files after replace

Tags: sql, powershell

I pretty new with PowerShell and I have written the following script. To get all the jobs from a map and alter the `@command` line to the new standard.

```cs
$sqlserver = 'currentserver'
$testservername = 'newcurrentserver'
$orgineel_submap = 'D:\Jobs_from_Server\Jobs_Orgineel_opdr_2.3'
$orgineel_submapnew ='D:\Jobs_from_Server\GUHQTSQL1281_TDBMSBI\Jobs_Orgineel_opdr_2.3\succes'
$orgineel_failure = 'D:\Jobs_from_Server\Jobs_Orgineel_opdr_2.3\failure'

$fileserver = Get-ChildItem $orgineel_submaporgineel *.sql 
$stringfile = '@command=N''/FILE'
$stringisserver = '@command=N''/ISSERVER'
$commandline = '@command=N'
$replaceline ="/Server " + """" + "\" + """" + $sqlserver + '\"" /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT' 

foreach ($fileser in $fileserver) {
    $targetfile = "$orgineel_submapnew\" + $fileser.Name.Replace("_Orgineel", "_new")
    $rejected = "$orgineel_failure\" + $fileser.Name.Replace("_Orgineel","_failure")

    $filename = $fileser.FullName 
    $file = Get-Content $filename

    #Replace servername if the@command in the sql job is '@command=N''/ISSERVER'
    if ($file -match $stringisserver) {
        $file = $file -replace $testservername, $sqlserver
    }

    #Here the @command lines that are now '@command=N''/FILE' are being traformed to the '@command=N''/ISSERVER' standard
    if ($file -match $stringfile) {
        $stap1 = $file -replace "/CONFIGFILE.*\"" " 
        $stap2 = $stap1 -replace "/CHECKPOINTING OFF", $replaceline
        $file = $stap2 -replace $stringfile, $stringisserver
    } 

    #Here is checked that the file @command is '@command=N''/ISSERVER' and if this is the case it will bie aved in de Succes map
    if ($file -match $stringisserver) {
        $file | Out-File $targetfile
    } else {  #Here will the .sql jobs by saved if they are not '@command=N''/ISSERVER' 
       $file | Out-File $rejected
    }
}
```

The script changes the required point like replacing `'@command=N''/FILE'` with `'@command=N''/ISSERVER` it also filters and put the jobs in rejected if they do not contain `'@command=N''/ISSERVER`.

My problem is that some files after the `foreach` loop contain multiple `@command` like for example:

```sql
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=N'/ISSERVER "\"" /SERVER "\"GUVMOSRV65430\O_DBMS_A\""
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Process, 
        @step_id=1, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=N'/FILE "\"" /SERVER "\"GUVMOSRV65430\O_DBMS_A\""
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
```

My question is: How can I ensure that files that do contain `@command=N'/ISSERVER`  will still be rejected if it also contains another `@command` line that does not match `@command=N'/ISSERVER`.

I have tried for example using `-match` and no-match plus a second `foreach` loop where it compares all `@command` lines and rejects without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have solved my problem by using the following code

```
$sqlserver = 'currentserver'
$testservername = 'newcurrentserver'
$orgineel_submap = 'D:\Jobs_from_Server\Jobs_Orgineel_opdr_2.3'
$orgineel_submapnew ='D:\Jobs_from_Server\GUHQTSQL1281_TDBMSBI\Jobs_Orgineel_opdr_2.3\succes'
$orgineel_failure = 'D:\Jobs_from_Server\Jobs_Orgineel_opdr_2.3\failure'

$fileserver = Get-ChildItem $orgineel_submaporgineel *.sql 
$stringfile = '@command=N''/FILE'
$stringisserver = '@command=N''/ISSERVER'
$commandline = '@command=N'
$replaceline ="/Server " + """" + "\" + """" + $sqlserver + '\"" /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT' 


foreach ($fileser in $fileserver) {

   # $doelbestand = $fileser.name + '.goed'

   $succes = "$submapchanged\" + $fileser.name #.replace("_oudeserver","_goed")
   $failure =  "$submapfailed\" + $fileser.name.replace("_goed","_fout")

    $filename = $fileser.fullname 
    $content = Get-Content $filename

 #Replace servername if the@command in the sql job is '@command=N''/ISSERVER'
    if ($content -match $commandline_new){
                 $content = $content -replace $sourceserver, $newsqlserver}

 #Here the @command lines that are now '@command=N''/FILE' are being traformed to the '@command=N''/ISSERVER' standard

    if ($content -match $commandline_old){
       $step1 =$content -replace "/CONFIGFILE.*\"" " 
       $step2 = $step1 -replace "/CHECKPOINTING OFF" , $stringtoreplace
       $step3 = $step2 -replace """\\""D:.*dtsx", $tijdelijkeveranderingregeltest 
       $content = $step3 -replace $commandline_old, $commandline_new

       } 

ForEach ($line in $content) 
{ 
  #write-host $line 
  if ($line.Contains($commandline)) 
  { 
     $index = $line.IndexOf($commandline) 
     $command = $line.Substring($index + 11, 9)

     if ($command -eq '/ISSERVER')
     {
     #       write-host 'GOED!'
      $content |out-file  $succes 
     }
     else
     {
           # write-host 'FOUT!'

      $content |out-file  $failure 
     }
 }} } 

#Removes the File die rejected is maar nog wel in de Job_aangepast staan
$rejected =  Get-ChildItem  $submapfailed *.sql  
foreach ($reject in $rejected) {  
    $fullname = $reject.fullname.replace("_fout", "_goed").replace("Jobs_Gefaald","Jobs_Aangepast")
    Remove-Item $fullname -erroraction silentlycontinue
    }
```

I have added a ForEach `($line in $content)` to loop trough all rows and check if the all are `'@command=N''/ISSERVER'` If this is the case it is saved in the map **success** if not it is saved in the map **failure**

Finally the following part removes the file from the **success** folder if it is also put in the folder **failure**

```
#Removes the File die rejected is maar nog wel in de Job_aangepast staan
$rejected =  Get-ChildItem  $submapfailed *.sql  
foreach ($reject in $rejected) {  
    $fullname = $reject.fullname.replace("_fout", "_goed").replace("Jobs_Gefaald","Jobs_Aangepast")
    Remove-Item $fullname -erroraction silentlycontinue
    }
```